# Pesonal google calendar sync with fullcalendar js

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I want to sync personal google calendar with my apps calender I used fullcalendar js in my project which take evens from mysql database please help me in doing this task

Comment: Just as an FYI, for simple tasks that involve operating on Google services, you may find Google Apps Script simpler and more convenient. Google Apps Script has a Calendar Service that allows you to operate on the data in Google Calendar: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/?csw=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fullCalendar can not fetch events from a personal google calendar. It must be a public google calendar. Just follow the instructions.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/google_calendar/